# Do puffin beaks have vertical slits or cracks?

Tags: ornithology

I have seen a photo where puffins seem to have vertical lines on their beaks.  It is uncertain if those are just line or actual slits or cracks in the beaks.  Do puffin beaks have slits or cracks?

Comment: Can you add a photo showing what you mean?

Comment: an image would be important, puffins shed portions of their bill, have varying thickness, and have color patterns anyone, then there are growth lines and cracks ass possibilities. Any of those could be what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I am concerned a healthy puffin hasn't got any slits or cracks in its beak. The lines that you see are literally just that - or little grooves. Obviously, beaks might show signs of wear and tear, so cracks may be observed. However, there are no genes in a puffin's genome that would lead to the expression of slits and cracks in its beak.

I think the photos below might help visualising.

[image]
(Photo: Tycho Anker-Nilssen, NINA)

[image]
(Photo: Will Nicholls)